# How to initialize an array with NamedTuples in Julia 1.6.0?

Tags: arrays, julia, namedtuple

I can initialize an array of tuples with `Array{Tuple{Int, Int}}(undef, 10)`.

However, I cannot make it work for named tuples. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way to do it (I understand you want an uninitialized array of `NamedTuples` having a concrete type):

```
julia> Array{NamedTuple{(:a, :b), Tuple{Int64, Float64}}}(undef, 10)
10-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:a, :b), Tuple{Int64, Float64}}}:
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 2.156699073e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 2.15670018e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)
 (a = 257472272, b = 1.272082044e-315)

julia> Array{NamedTuple{(:a, :b), Tuple{Int64, String}}}(undef, 10)
10-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:a, :b), Tuple{Int64, String}}}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Vector` instead of `Array`?

Comment: It can be both. `Array` takes the second argument to determine the dimensionality of the output, see the codes in boot.jl around line 462. I used `Array` as the question used `Array` and did not ask about a vector specifically but about array in general.

Comment: you can also use `typeof`: `Array{typeof((a=1,b=2))}(undef,10)`

Comment: @AndrejOskin `Vector{T}` is just an alias for `Array{T,1}`. The dimensionality of the array is inferred from the second or varargs argument of the constructor; it can be either `NTuple{Integer,N}` or `Varargs{Integer,N}` and in both cases the dimensionality of the array will be `N`. So `10` and `(10,)` as the second argument both create a 1D array, `10, 11` (varargs) and `(10, 11)` (2-tuple) would both create a 2D array, etc.